# Excel not recognising all dates in same column

Tags: excel, date, time, format

I paste the following in excel, half of them are not recognized as date in excel.

Have already tried text to columns, adding 0 to them. I think exhausted all online techniques.

My target is to convert them all this to this format yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss

```
9/25/19 19:17
12/5/19 14:28
11/4/19 16:46
3/20/19 14:12
1/2/20 21:15
3/20/19 19:24
3/14/19 20:03
12/29/19 20:24
3/18/19 10:20
3/9/19 11:03
12/16/19 16:01
12/21/19 19:31
12/17/19 11:41
10/12/19 17:09
3/25/19 14:01
11/20/19 21:02
8/28/19 19:00
3/14/19 20:00
3/29/19 1:39
8/30/19 22:04
3/10/19 20:02
11/20/19 8:37
9/15/19 19:19
3/20/19 17:12
8/26/19 11:03
8/30/19 22:16
7/31/19 14:53
3/25/19 20:14
1/26/20 10:24
3/29/19 1:12
6/27/19 10:06
10/15/19 14:05
12/28/19 10:58
10/23/19 13:58
8/25/19 16:07
3/27/19 16:28
3/23/19 11:26
3/24/19 11:13
3/18/19 10:11
3/25/19 13:39
3/26/19 16:35
3/27/19 21:11
11/27/19 13:23
```

Comment: When I paste the list in Excel they are all recognized as dates (which really means they are all recognized as numbers). Have you changed the entire columns format to `General`?

Comment: Have you tried `=TEXT(A1,"yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")` and dropping down?

Answer (score 0):

The data sample uses the MDY order. If Excel doesn't recognize half of these as dates, your regional settings use the DMY order.

Instead of pasting the data into Excel, put it into a text file and then open the text file with Excel. That will launch the Text Import Wizard.

[image]

Keep **Delimited** selected and click **Next**

In Step 2, click **Space** and click **Next**. Date and time will now be split into two columns.

In Step 3 of 3, select the first column and  click the Date radio button and set the drop-down to **MDY**.

[image]

Click **Finish** and the data will be in your worksheet as dates.

[image]

You can now use formulas to bring the time and date back together by adding the cells, `=A1+B1`  - and then use formatting to display the date/time values any way you want.